# Program compiled in Linux doesn't detect '\n' line breaks in fstream where Windows runtime does

Tags: c++, linux, visual-studio, gcc, g++

EDITED:

In some parts of my code, I use the `peek()` function on an fstream to see if the next character in an opened `.txt` file is a line break, which I believe to be defined in my `.txt` files as the character `\n`. When compiled and run in Windows, my program runs as it should and interprets each line break in the opened file as `\n`. However, when I run the same program in Linux, compiled with g++, my `if (file.peek() != '\n')` statements return `true` when the current position is at the end of a line in the file (incorrect) where Windows returned the same statements as being `false` (correct). Why is this? **Are new lines defined by a character other than `\n` in opened `.txt` files in Linux vs in Windows?**

Code Snippet:

```
if (counter % 5 == 0){
    cout << "counter % 5 = " << counter % 5 << endl;
    cout << "counter = " << counter << ". " << "true: (counter % 5 == 0)" << endl;
    if (counter < 125){
        cout << "counter = " << counter << ". " << "true: (counter < 25)" << endl;
        if (file.peek() != '\n'){
            cout << "counter = " << counter << ". " << "returned false on (file.peek() != \'\\n\')" << endl;
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Terminal Output (g++):

```
counter % 5 = 0
counter = 5. true: (counter % 5 == 0)
counter = 5. true: (counter < 25)
counter = 5. returned false on (file.peek() != '\n')
```

---

Here is the `.txt` file I'm trying to copy in as a string:

test.txt:

```
1 1 0 1 0
0 0 0 1 0
1 1 1 1 0
1 0 0 0 0
1 0 0 0 0

0 1 0 1 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
1 0 0 0 0

0 1 0 1 0
0 1 0 0 0
0 1 1 1 0
0 0 0 0 0
1 0 0 0 0

0 0 0 1 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 0
0 0 0 0 0
1 0 0 0 0

0 0 0 1 0
0 0 0 1 0
0 0 0 1 0
0 0 0 0 0
1 1 1 1 1
```

Main.cpp:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#pragma once

using namespace std;

bool importMaze(string file_name){
    fstream file;
    string inMaze = "";
    string finalMaze = "";
    int counter = 1;

    file.open(file_name.c_str());

    while (file >> inMaze){
        bool noSpace = false;
        bool addLine = false;
        bool addSecondLine = false;

        if (inMaze != "0" && inMaze != "1"){
            cout << "counter = " << counter << ". " << "returned false on (inMaze != \"0\" && inMaze != \"1\")" << endl;
            return false;
        }
        if (counter == 1 && inMaze != "1"){
            cout << counter << ": " << "returned false on (counter == 1 && inMaze != \"1\")" << endl;
            return false;
        }
        if (counter == 125 && inMaze != "1"){
            cout << "counter = " << counter << ". " << "returned false on (counter == 125 && inMaze != \"1\")" << endl;
            return false;
        }
        if (counter % 5 != 0 && file.peek() == '\n'){
            cout << "counter = " << counter << ". " << "false on (counter % 5 != 0 && file.peek() == \'\\n\')" << endl;
            return false;
        }
        if (counter % 5 == 0 && counter < 125 && file.peek() == '\n'){
            addLine = true;
            noSpace = true;
            if (counter % 25 != 0){
                file.seekg(2, ios::cur);
                char test = file.peek();
                if (file.peek() == '\n'){
                    cout << "counter = " << counter << ". " << "returned false on counter % 25 != 0 and (file.peek() == \'\\n\')" << endl;
                    return false;
                }
                file.seekg(-2, ios::cur);
            }
            if (counter % 25 == 0 && counter < 125){
                file.seekg(1, ios::cur);
                if (file.peek() == '\n'){
                    addSecondLine = true;
                }
                if (file.peek() != '\n'){
                    cout << "counter = " << counter << ". " << "returned false on counter % 25 == 0 and (file.peek() != \'\\n\')" << endl;
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

        /** Returns false when should be true */

        if (counter % 5 == 0){
            cout << "counter % 5 = " << counter % 5 << endl;
            cout << "counter = " << counter << ". " << "true: (counter % 5 == 0)" << endl;
            if (counter < 125){
                cout << "counter = " << counter << ". " << "true: (counter < 25)" << endl;
                if (file.peek() != '\n'){
                    cout << "counter = " << counter << ". " << "returned false on (file.peek() != \'\\n\')" << endl;
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

        /** ^^ Returns false when shoulld be true ^^ */

        if (counter == 125 && file.peek() == '\n'){
            cout << "counter = " << counter << ". " << "returned false on (counter == 125 && file.peek() == \'\\n\')" << endl << "inMaze:" << endl << inMaze << endl << "finalMaze:" << finalMaze << endl;
            return false;
        }
        if (counter == 125){
            noSpace = true;
        }
        finalMaze += inMaze;
        if (noSpace == false){
            finalMaze += " ";
        }
        if (addLine == true){
            finalMaze += "\n";
        }
        if (addSecondLine == true){
            finalMaze += "\n";
        }
        inMaze.clear();
        counter++;
    }
    cout << finalMaze;
    return true;
}

int main(){

    importMaze("test.txt");
}
```

Comment: What are the file peeks for?

Comment: To make sure the file being passed in is in the correct 5x5x5 format. So I use peek() every 5 digits to make sure there's a `\n` there. (and every 25 to ensure there are 2 `\n`'s there)

Comment: Does your test file have DOS-style `\r\n` line-endings?

Comment: You claim that _"I cout what counter % 5 computes to (0) and it still marks if (counter % 5 == 0) statement as false!"_ but that's nonsense, you print "false on" but that doesn't mean it is actually false, the `if` condition evaluates to true, otherwise it wouldn't print anything. `counter % 5` is zero, i.e. false, but `counter % 5 == 0` is true.

Comment: Oh brother. I've been working on this for too long. Now I see why you're so concerned with the line breaks in the file. Because that's obviously the problem here. I expect a \n but there's actually something else there.

Comment: Exactly. Which is obvious if you're dealt with this kind of thing many times ("this program using fstream works differently on Windows and Linux" almost always means a problem with line-endings). Don't be so quick to dismiss an educated guess and assume the compiler is buggy :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You claim that:

> I cout what counter % 5 computes to (0) and it still marks if (counter % 5 == 0) statement as false!

but that's nonsense. You print the words "false on" but that doesn't mean it is actually false. The `if` condition evaluates to true, otherwise it wouldn't print anything! `counter % 5` is zero, i.e. false, but `counter % 5 == 0` is true.

Using your own tutorialspoint.com link I ran `file test.txt` at the shell prompt and got:

```
test.txt: ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators
```

so the problem is the DOS-style line-endings, and nothing to do with g++ not knowing how to compile C++ (which should have been obvious, because g++ is an excellent compiler and far more likely to get C++ right than you are! See [the first rule of programming](http://blog.codinghorror.com/the-first-rule-of-programming-its-always-your-fault/))

You are misinterpreting the fact that the line doesn't end with `\n` and blaming the compiler for doing arithmetic wrong. The file stream is opened in text mode, which means on Windows the runtime removes the `\r` characters from `\r\n` sequences, but on GNU/Linux text mode and binary mode are equivalent and the input is not modified. You either need to handle the `\r` characters explicitly in your code, or fix the input file to remove the characters before you read the file.

Comment: Yup, pretty pathetic on my end. I thought running on low sleep was a worthy sacrifice to get more programming done, but I think more rest may have led to prevention of lots of these brain shortages. However, I did NOT know that Windows runtime removed the \r from \r\n whereas Linux does not. It's for that bit of information alone that I will keep this question around in stead of deleting it out of sheer embarrassment. Thank you for your help.

Comment: And though I implied it was a bug with the compiler, I certainly knew it was something incorrect I had done in my code. I strongly doubt I'll ever be the one to find a bug in a compiler (ha). I was moreso asking "What did I do wrong to make the g++ compiled code act differently than in the Windows environment? / What did I do to confuse the compiler?" (Though that last q admittedly still wasn't the correct question to ask--the compiler was never "confused" or behaved unexpectedly..)